# How to make a wifi device to connect to a internet enabled Router and also acting itself as a hotspot?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless

I am trying to create a wireless network+ hotspot in raspberry pi 2(RPi) using Edimax EW-7811Un wifi dongle.
The RPi should be able to broadcast its IP-address so that clients can connect and it should  also get connected to a router.

Tried 2 ways so far,

1. I have created a hotspot in RPi and the clients was able to connect to it but the I dont know whether I can connect to the Router without closing the hotspot.
2. I was able to connect to router but the clients cant connect to Rpi directly since RPi is not in AP mode.

On typing `iw` command, my wifi dongle supports the following modes,

`IBSS
Managed
AP
Monitor
P2P - GO
P2P - Client`

Is there any way to make RPi both as an Access-point as well as  connected to router(Managed mode).?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can't. If you do want it, you will need the right hardware for the job. Specifically, you'll want an adapter that supports *virtual interfaces*.

Unfortunately, your adapter does not support that feature. I know some Atheros adapters do. My TP-Link WN-722N supports that.

After you acquire the hardware, simply sprinkle some `iw` command sorcery to create a client and an AP interface, add some routing/NAT rules (i.e. `iptables`/`route`) and you'll be good to go.